# Asp.net web api returns a 400 only if consumed by 3G Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I know it's a strange question, but it's 3 days we are banging our heads against the wall!

We have a web api application (asp.net 4 c#) running on IIS from severals month with no problem. 
From some day some of our customers are stating they cannot consume api anymore.

After some (a lot...) of investigation the problem seem to be a post to an api. The strange thing is it works with no any problem with wi-fi or 3G. Only 3G from a particular carrier seem not to work.

This is a comparison to the headers of two requests done from the same tablet to the same server the first in wi-fi, the latter in 3G.

******************WIFI (Response: 200)

```
- Http: Request, POST /api_name/delivery , Using Basic Authorization
   Command: POST
 - URI: /api_name/delivery
 Location: /api_name/delivery 
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
UserAgent:  App_Android
ContentLength:  9788
  - ContentType:  multipart/form-data; boundary=u3_y3iyl55Ep7eN3jnrrCX9i_rNK4z1XBPipaq
   - MediaType:  multipart/form-data; boundary=u3_y3iyl55Ep7eN3jnrrCX9i_rNK4z1XBPipaq
  MainType:  multipart/form-data
- MimeBoundary: u3_y3iyl55Ep7eN3jnrrCX9i_rNK4z1XBPipaq
   Boundary: u3_y3iyl55Ep7eN3jnrrCX9i_rNK4z1XBPipaq
Host:  some_ip:80
Connection:  Keep-Alive
 - Authorization: Basic
 - Authorization:  Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
  WhiteSpace:  
- BasicAuthorization: 
   Scheme: Basic
 - Realm: test:test
  - Realm: test:test
     UserId: test
     PassWord: test
HeaderEnd: CRLF
 - MimeBody: multipart
   Boundary: --u3_y3iyl55Ep7eN3jnrrCX9i_rNK4z1XBPipaq
  - MultiPartEntity: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    - Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data"
     Mainpart: form-data; name="Data"
    - ContentType: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
     MediaType: text - textual information
     - SubContentType: plain; charset=US-ASCII
      SubType: plain - text containing no formatting commands or directives of any sort
      Parameters:  charset=US-ASCII
    - Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
     Mainpart: 8bit
    HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

****************CELL (Response 400 Bad Request - Invalid Verb)

```
- Http: Request, POST /api_name/delivery , Using Basic Authorization
Command: POST
 - URI: /api_name/delivery
     Location: /api_name/delivery 
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
 - Authorization: Basic
  - Authorization:  Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
     WhiteSpace:  
   - BasicAuthorization: 
      Scheme: Basic
    - Realm: test:test
    - Realm: test:test
        UserId: test
        PassWord: test
    Host:  some_ip:80
    UserAgent:  App_Android
    ContentLength:  9786
  - ContentType:  multipart/form-data;boundary=bAwxUZAdKQlR5y4yyDOQVgV4Xxj9rhAdW33CV
   - MediaType:  multipart/form-data;boundary=bAwxUZAdKQlR5y4yyDOQVgV4Xxj9rhAdW33CV
      MainType:  multipart/form-data
    - MimeBoundary: bAwxUZAdKQlR5y4yyDOQVgV4Xxj9rhAdW33CV
       Boundary: bAwxUZAdKQlR5y4yyDOQVgV4Xxj9rhAdW33CV
    Connection:  Keep-Alive
    HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

This is the logcat from the app

```
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC     "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
10-01 19:16:10.859: D/PostDeliveryRequest(23353): </BODY></HTML>
```

Do you see something strange?

Thanks Stefano

Comment: Anything in the IIS logs?

Comment: Yes iis gives "400 Bad request - Invalid Verb"

Comment: Have you tried using HTTPS for your service?  Perhaps the cellular provider won't mangle your request if it's ssl.

Comment: Tried both http and https with same result

Comment: This is my only other suggestion.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setnotransforms(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you think the 2 byte difference in content length is significant, or can you explain that?  Can you post a complete hex dump of the failing request?  Some of the chars that look like whitespace may not be legal.

Comment: this is https.sys log
2014-10-02 10:07:34 109.53.111.83 57132 192.168.1.51 80 - - - 400 - Verb -